# How do I (easily) delete a constraint in Interface Builder in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, autolayout, xcode6

Assume you've selected an object and you have the Size Selector in the Utilities panel open. You can see the list of constraints applied to the object. In the list of constraints you could click on the little gear and pick delete. You can't in Xcode 6.

There are still several ways to delete constraints in IB:

- Find the constraint in the Document Outline and delete it that way (but it can be hard to find).
- Click on the little bar in the storyboard and delete it that way (which can be hard to click on).
- Double click on the constraint in the Size Selector which will open Attribute Inspector and highlight the constraint in the Document Outline. This can be a nuisance when you want to delete several.

Still, I miss ease of use of the gear delete feature and I'm wondering if it's still there in a similar fashion and I just can find it. While the other ways work, I find myself wasting lots of time especially when playing with the new Size Classes feature. So, find a easier way to delete them?

Comment: I have noticed this as well.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem. But if you activate a constraint in the Document Outline, it will be highlighted in the storyboard. When you activate the right one, it should be very easy to delete it.

Comment: When I work with constraints usually by selecting an object and using the Size Selector. That give you a list of constraints effecting the object without having to search through a long list which may or may not relate to this object. The Document Outline also has a max width and often I can't read the full constraint since it gets truncated. It's also just fairly annoying to have to bounce back and force between the Size Selector and the Document Outline, especially when we never had to in the past.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In Xcode6 (Beta5) when I click on a particular constraint in the Size inspector, it acquires a thin blue border. The constraint can then be deleted using the backspace.

Comment: I'll second this one. In Xcode 6 beta 5, you can select and delete a constraint straight out of the Size Inspector. Yay!

Comment: I just tried this in Xcode 6.3.2 and it just deletes the object itself, rather than the constraint. Even though I clicked on the constraint in Size Inspector until it was dark blue and the others were grayed out.

Comment: This just disables the constraint and doesn't actually delete it. The only way I have found to delete the constraint is to select it in the layer list to the left of the storyboard canvas.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is right, but there is so much **frustration with selecting constraints that lay outside of selected view** that I decided to add this tips as another answer.

I found [incredible list of tips](http://nixtechnica.blogspot.ru/2008/06/how-to-take-screenshot-in-mac-with.html) that helped me to solve this problem.

**The problem:**

1. You select the view and Xcode shows related constraints.
2. You try to choose the one that is outside of selected view.
3. You fail (end with selecting the view beneath the constraint)

[image]

**Soulution:**

Click it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed and you'll see a menu of all the views that exist where you've clicked.

To delete selected constraint press <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: I access the same menu using ctrl + right click, but I'm going to try your way and see if I like it better. :)

Comment: In XCode 6.4 I do these finger gymnastics, but it doesn't show the constraint in the menu for an "image view".  The only way I seem to be able to access the constraint is through the top context bar. That allows me to select the constrain and uncheck "Installed". Unfortunately, I've found no way to delete it.

Comment: @nueverest If my method doesn't work for you, you can select constraint in the left sidebar (document outline). If constraint is selected that way, pressing `delete` key removes it completely. If you want to quickly uninstall constraint for current layout, select the element, select its constraint in right sidebar (in size inspector) and then press `delete` key.

Comment: @DanSkeel thanks clicking the "Show Document Outline" button and scrolling down to the constraint then pressing `delete` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is incomplete. When you delete the constraint from the Size Inspector, you are leaving behind the constraint object in the Document Outline pane. It is greyed out, meaning it is not used, but still exists and, what's worse, will affect auto layout with errors, warnings or conflicting constraints and you will go crazy until you also delete them from the Document Outline pane.

So:

```
1. Delete the constraint from the Size Inspector as in the accepted answer
2. Delete any greyed out constraints from the Document Outline
```

Live a happy, constraint-free life.

Comment: Is there some way to easily delete the one from the Document Outline? It can be very error-prone to hunt down the precise constraint when there are 10+ constraints listed.

Comment: Just found something, check newest answer!

Answer (score 0):

[This answer from @wayne chi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31281967/144088) is the simplest, and spares you from hunting down constraints in Document Outline:

Double click the grayed out constraint (switches focus to the constraint) then press delete. This will delete the constraint.

Comment: What when you want to go back to the list of constraints? When I double click I can see only that constraint, but I don't know how to get back to see the others.

Comment: @TimSim after double clicking, you will see the constraint. Press the `delete` key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the easiest way is to close the file in Xcode and edit it with a text editor. :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete ALL constraints from a viewController simply turn off auto layout and then reenable it (or don't) and all of the constraints will be gone.