# iOS 8 Xcode 6: What's the point of the grayed out constraints?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

In the Xcode 6 betas, when I delete a constraint, it doesn't remove it completely, but grays it out. I thought that was to imply that the constraint was used in a different size class, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Also, how do you permanently delete these constraints?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few ways to delete the constraints from the Storyboard

1. Try not to delete from the Storyboard object because sometimes different constraints can stack together and you might delete the wrong one. So, it is better to delete from the **Document Outline**. Just highlight the constraint that you want to delete on the **Document Outline** and just press **delete** button on your keyboard. See screen shot below:
   [image]
2. If you want to clear all the constraints from a selected view, Select the View (eg: A button), Tap on the Third Button (**Resolve Auto Layout Issues Button**), Tap **Clear Constraints**.
   [image]
3. If you want to clear all the constraints for all the views inside the view controller, Highlight the right view controller Object inside the storyboard, Tap on the Third Button (**Resolve Auto Layout Issues Button**), Tap **Clear Constraints** under the "All Views in the View Controller".

Comment: Thanks @Ricky. Your answer lead me to figure out the best way to delete constraints (including grayed out constraints).

Comment: NO problem. I am glad that I am able to help. ;)

Comment: This is a good answer for half the question, but it doesn't answer the meat of it: Why? Why can't you completely delete a constraint from the size inspector?!

Answer (score 8):

Double click the grayed out constraint (switches focus to the constraint) then press delete. This will delete the constraint.

Comment: The easiest and probably best way to completely delete a constraint (grey or not), especially if you cannot find it in the Document Outline on the left!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer to the following question is that you can have same constraint selectively "installed" (or to my understanding, enabled) for different size classes.  After you select a constraint from Document Outline, you can click on the + sign to Add Size Class Customization from the bottom of Attribute Inspector.  So when you delete a constraint from the Size Inspector, you're basically deleting a constraint for **a particular size class only**.  In order to delete a constraint for all size classes, you have to delete from Document Outline.

> Why? Why can't you completely delete a constraint from the size
>   inspector?!

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete grayed out constraints from the right hand Size Inspector (which is where I normally delete constraints because it's much easier to ascertain which view the constraints are for, it get's really confusing in the Document Outline), but you can delete the same grayed out constraints from the Document Outline on the left by selecting them and hitting the delete button.

Example of grayed out constraint (see height):

[image]

**Note:** To make the Document Outline's constraints easier to digest, I first delete them from the Size Inspector, which grays them out, then delete the newly grayed out constraint from the Size Inspector. Just FYI.

Comment: I think you have 2 questions here and I answered one of them. Can you show me the screen short of the greyed out constraints? I don't understand what you meant by that. I think you should put this on the comment instead on the answer.

Comment: See this [cool tutorial on size classes](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial) and you will see the point.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of size classes, you can disable size classes from File Inspector and every greyed constraints runs out, you can re-enable them again if you need them.

Hope it helps